# How to fix csv to json converter module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't figure out how to match the title and genre correctly based on what I have in my module.

The csv_json module has an exception where it doesn't match each of the properties accordingly and that is when the title has "The" in it.

`//csv file`

movieId,title,genre

1,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
2,"Creation, The creator(xxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
3,"Destruction, The destroyer(xxxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance

```js
//csv_json module 
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

function readCsv(pathToFile) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const csvReader = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(pathToFile)
        });

        let headers;
        const rows = [];
        let tempRows = [];
        csvReader
            .on('line', row => {
                if (!headers) {
                    headers = row.split(','); // header name breed age
                } else {
                    rows.push(row.split(','));
                }
            })
            .on('close', () => {
                // then iterate through all of the "rows", matching them to the "headers"
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var obj = {};
                    var currentline = rows[i];

                    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j]; //Kitty Siamese 14
                    }

                    tempRows.push(obj);
                }

                resolve(JSON.stringify(tempRows));
            });

        // This would be in place of the "return" statement you had before
    });
}

module.exports = readCsv;
```

```
//js file
const readCsv = require('./csvjson.js');

readCsv('movieTest.csv').then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    let movieJson = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(movieJson)


/*data output:
[{"movieId":"1","title":"\"American President","genre":" The (1995)\""},{"movieId":"2","title":"\"Creation","genre":" The creator(xxxx)\""},{"movieId":"3","title":"\"Destruction","genre":" The destroyer(xxxxx)\""}]

*/
/*movieJson output:
[ { movieId: '1',
    title: '"American President',
    genre: ' The (1995)"' },
  { movieId: '2',
    title: '"Creation',
    genre: ' The creator(xxxx)"' },
  { movieId: '3',
    title: '"Destruction',
    genre: ' The destroyer(xxxxx)"' } ]
*/
});
```

I expect the output to match:

```js
[ { movieId: '1',
    title: "American President, The (1995)",
    genre:'Comedy|Drama|Romance' },
  { movieId: '2',
    title: "The creator(xxxx) Creation",
    genre: ' Comedy|Drama|Romance' },
  { movieId: '3',
    title: "Destruction The destroyer(xxx)",
    genre: ' Comedy|Drama|Romance' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably since you're splitting each row on every occurrence of a comma.

```
const row = '1,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance'
row.split(',')
// returns ["1", ""American President", " The (1995)"", "Comedy|Drama|Romance"]
```

Try replacing every comma that is not followed by a whitespace with some unique string that wouldn't occur anywhere else in the CSV file, and then split on that:

```
row.replace(/\,(\S)/g, '&unique;$1').split('&unique;')
// returns ["1", ""American President, The (1995)"", "Comedy|Drama|Romance"]
```

Hope this helps! :)